# What is the maximum timestamp numpy.datetime64 can handle?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, datetime64

I'm trying to convert `datetime` to `numpy.datetime64` but the following case fails:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> np.datetime64(datetime.max)
OSError: Failed to use 'localtime_s' to convert to a local time
```

I presume that `datetime64` can't handle such far-dated timestamps.

So what is the maximum timestamp that `datetime64` can handle?

Comment: One important thing if you get an ``OSError`` is to include which ``OS`` you are using in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what the specified unit of your `np.datetime64` object is (according to the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units)). Since you have given a timestamp with microseconds the allowed range is `[290301 BC, 294241 AD]`.

This answered your question but I think the unspoken other question is why it throws an Exception:

I'm facing the same error (using Windows) and I tried `a=np.datetime64(datetime.max)` which works. Therefore I suspect the problem is *NOT* the `np.datetime64` span (because creating such a `datetime` works) but that the `__repr__` requires the OS in some way and probably the OS limits it in your case. So check what's the maximum localtime of your OS and for every datetime after that you can still work with the `np.datetime64` objects but cannot print them on screen. :-)