# What is the largest datetime in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and trying to read a date from excel. For validation, when I use 'pd.to_datetime' to compare against another datetime object, for date 9999-12-31, I am getting an exception: 'OutofBoundsDateTime', whereas I believe this should still be a valid MAXDATE as per standards.
Here is a sample code where I am facing such issue:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["9999-12-31"])
pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```

Executing the above code results into OutofBoundsDateTime exception. Whereas if I choose any other date, there is no such exception.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35415247/12416453

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something like `np.iinfo` / `np.finfo` for `datetime`.

Comment: You can use `datetime.datetime.max` ---> `datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)` but don't if this holds true with `np.datetime64`

Comment: Considier asking the pandas team at github. Your ask is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. Have raised to pandas team at github